# JasperReports Server - Error generating reports with scheduler

Tags: quartz-scheduler, jasperserver

every week on monday we are generating some reports in the morning. We have no problem with the most of them, but 2 are failing sometimes (irregular).

This is the stacktrace of the exception we get with e-mail:

```
ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1704)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1792)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1828)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.domain.util.FileBufferedOutputStream.ensureFileOutput(FileBufferedOutputStream.java:144)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.domain.util.FileBufferedOutputStream.write(FileBufferedOutputStream.java:164)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:109)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.OutputStreamCounter.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:109)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStream.toPdf(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject.writeTo(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addToBody(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.newPage(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.Document.newPage(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:686)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:396)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.exportToPdf(EngineServiceImpl.java:548)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.PdfReportOutput.getOutput(PdfReportOutput.java:95)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.executeAndSendReport(ReportExecutionJob.java:485)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.execute(ReportExecutionJob.java:217)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
```

Have someone an idea why some are failing and the most of them not?
We are using *JasperReports Server 4.7* on a Linuxserver (Debian) with a *Tomcat*.

Answer (score 0):

I see the error 'No such file or directory' which makes me wonder where you are saving the output?  Is it being emailed, saved to the repository, or saved somewhere on the file system?